# "<?php" in first line of all PHP files gets automatically deleted every 2-3 weeks

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony

We have two sites running on Wordpress and Symfony, hosted on Bluehost.com

Every 2-3 weeks, we see this following error on our site.

```
/** 
  * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads 
  * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme. 
  * 
  * @package WordPress 
  */ 
/** 
  * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it. 
  * 
  * @var bool 
  */ 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true); 
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */ 
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

A freelance developer has told us that for some reason the first line of all php files `<?php` keeps getting deleted.

We then have to restore the sites from our backup.

Any thoughts/ideas/solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your site is been hacked one or other way, and then some antivirus might try to clean files and delete those lines accidently. Get a fresh install of wordpress and ask your developer to clear your symfony2 site as well.

Comment: I think you need to contact your webhost about it.

Comment: @SumitGupta, Yes if the site was hacked wouldn't the host notice?

Comment: @user2698845 not necessarily, unless the hacking involves a large load on the server.

Comment: @user2698845 Shared hosting provider do not care about security of the userland code at all. The "hack" can be from their side (anti-virus or else), or from yours (old plugins, not up to date version of wordpress...).

Update everything, and if the hack append again, switch host.

Comment: Also change serwer password ;)

Comment: @user2698845 I do 2-3 wordpress per week, and 100% case I have seen like this are only because of old version of wordpress or plugin or bad plugin codes. So even if you contact your host nothing is going to happen, just get everything latest and it will be fixed until another new version of wordpress and their plugin gets released.